# Azure storage account file share мониторинг места

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Всем привет,

Из официальной документации выяснилось, что мониторить место для нескольких file share в одном storage account нельзя:

> If the file share is a standard file share, the File Share dimension will not list the file share(s) because per-share metrics are not available for standard file shares. Alerts for standard file shares are based on all file shares in the storage account. Since per-share metrics are not available for standard file shares, the recommendation is to have one file share per storage account.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-monitoring?tabs=azure-portal#how-to-create-an-alert-if-the-azure-file-share-size-is-80-of-capacity

Может есть какие-то варианты или команды как это делать это через azure cli?

Answer (score 0):

Azure CLI и прочие инструменты повторяют тоже, что можно сделать через портал, используя API, дополнительных возможностей там нет, скорее наоборот.

Согласно документации, вы можете мониторить пространство, разнеся File Share по разным Storage аккаунтам.